# I wanted to prove the claim "A graph is a tree if and only if it has one fewer edge than it has vertices." Is this true or false, and why?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

For this question I chose 4 as the answer however it was wrong.
Can someone please explain the right answer
This were the choices:

Suppose I wanted to prove the claim "A graph is a tree if and only if it has one fewer edge than it has vertices."  Is this true or false, and why?

1. This is true, because it is a known fact that the number of edges in a tree is one less than the number of vertices.
2. This is false, because one can construct a disconnected graph with five vertices and four edges that is not a tree.
3. This is false, because trees do not always have a number of edges equal to the number of vertices minus one.
4. This is true, because the number of edges in a tree is always one less than the number of vertices, and also, you can't construct a graph that is not a tree if the number of edges is one less than the number of vertices.  So both directions of the iff are satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a cycle on 3 vertices $A,B,C$ and a stand-alone vertex $D$. You have 4 vertices, 3 edges and clearly not a tree.

But if you additionally assume $G$ is simple and connected, the claim is true.

Comment: But then that graph would not be a tree since not all vertices are connected?

Comment: What is your definition of tree? The graph in @gt6989's claim is not a tree, but that's the whole point. You claimed it had to be a tree, and he showed that it did *not* have to be a tree.

Comment: Oh man the answer is 2!!! I misinterpreted the question... Thanks!

Comment: @DenadaBakiasi exactly